# Determine a subverion branch's ancestor branch

Tags: svn

I have a long running subversion branch. I am trying to determine whether is has any other branch as an ancestor. For example, if I am on branch `staging` the following command would be perfect:

```
> svn log --show-ancestor-branch
trunk
```

Answer (score 3):

Run `svn log --stop-on-copy MYBRANCH`. The oldest log will tell you where it was copied from.